# Abstracting ownership with pointer wrapper

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to have auto-magic ownership handling of a dependency that I pass into another object.

That means if the dependency is referenced via a raw pointer there should be no ownership transfer but if it's referenced via `unique_ptr` the dependency should be managed by the object I passed it in.

To support this I thought to use type erasure fort the underlying pointer type. The thing I came up with seems to work but I'm not sure if this is really the right way to do it. So my question is: Is this ok or is there another/better pattern for this.

```
template <typename T>
struct UberPtr
{
    UberPtr(T* v) : tag(POINTER), ptr(v) {}

    UberPtr(std::unique_ptr<T>&& v) : tag(UNIQUE_PTR), uPtr(std::move(v)) {}

    UberPtr(std::shared_ptr<T> v) : tag(SHARED_PTR), sPtr(v) {}

    UberPtr(UberPtr<T>&& other)
    {
        tag = other.tag;

        if (other.tag == UNIQUE_PTR)
        {
            std::swap(uPtr, other.uPtr);
        }
        else if (other.tag == SHARED_PTR)
        {
            std::swap(sPtr, other.sPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            std::swap(ptr, other.ptr);
        }

        other.tag = POINTER;
    }

    ~UberPtr()
    {
        if (tag == UNIQUE_PTR)
        {
            uPtr.get_deleter()(uPtr.get());
        }
        else if (tag == SHARED_PTR)
        {
            sPtr.~shared_ptr();
        }
    }

    T& operator*() const
    {
        if (tag == POINTER)
        {
            return *ptr;
        }
        else if (tag == UNIQUE_PTR)
        {
            return *uPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            return *sPtr;
        }
    }

    T* operator->() const
    {
        if (tag == POINTER)
        {
            return ptr;
        }
        else if (tag == UNIQUE_PTR)
        {
            return uPtr.get();
        }
        else
        {
            return sPtr.get();
        }
    }

private:
    enum {POINTER,UNIQUE_PTR,SHARED_PTR} tag;
    union
    {
        T* ptr;
        std::unique_ptr<T> uPtr;
        std::shared_ptr<T> sPtr;
    };

};

template <typename T>
auto make_uber(T&& t, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_pointer_v<T>>* = nullptr)
{
    UberPtr<typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::element_type> uberPtr(std::forward<T>(t));
    return uberPtr;
}

template <typename T>
auto make_uber(T t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>>* = nullptr)
{
    UberPtr<typename std::remove_pointer_t<T>> uberPtr(t);
    return uberPtr;
}
```

Note that I'm pre `std::variant` that's why I'm using a good old union here.

Edit because it was mentioned in the comments:

I'm aware of the additional branching cost on deref. In my tests (clang only) everything was properly inlined and multiple derefs in the same context were optimised away so this branch was the only additional overhead I have seen.

Where I want to use this are library classes that cannot know about ownership. APIs I have seen often supply method overloads with a boolean "owned" parameter to support this and those than obviously needed to do branching as well.

So this question is not about performance implications but more if I can get something similar with std classes already.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea... There is already some overhead when you use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and you would add even bigger overhead. Also, your code don't support `std::weak_ptr` and won't help you if you want to share data further... Usually, you should know what you need. If not, then you should use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Phil1970 thanks! 2 questions: (1) I understand the additional overhead of `shared_ptr` but what would that be in case of `unique_ptr`? I always thought this would be 0 overhead? (2) What aspect of `weak_ptr`s are not supported? This class just wraps a `shared_ptr` (if one is passed in) and should not break anything there?

Comment: The more code you add, you make it harder for the compiler to optimize. For each access, you have to check the pointer type to decide which code is executed.